# Security reasons to maintain a whitelist of allowed HTTP response headers

Tags: security, http, header, firewall

As a web developer, I'm increasingly debugging issues only to find that our IT department are using our firewall to filter HTTP response headers.

They are using a whitelist of known headers, so certain newer technologies (CORS, websockets, etc) are automatically stripped until I debug the problem and request whitelisting.

The affected responses are third-party services we are consuming - so if we have an internal site that uses disqus, comments cannot be loaded because the response from disqus is having it's headers stripped. The resources we are serving are not affected, as it's only traffic coming in to the office.

Are there genuine reasons to block certain headers? Obviously there are concerns such as man-in-the-middle, redirects to phishing sites etc but these require more than just an errant header to be successful.

What are the security reasons to maintain a whitelist of allowed HTTP response headers?

Comment: Server and framework versions for example, which can expose exploits applicable to that version.

Comment: Interesting point. These are response headers of services our site is consuming (such as pinterest, mapbox, disqus) rather than of resources we are serving to the public. I'll amend my question to make this more clear.

Comment: They remove headers from _incoming_ HTTP requests? Then I would strongly advice to talk to your IT department and ask _them_ for a rationale, as I can't think of any logical explanation for that.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've done but they're digging in. I'm asking on here to support or debunk my understanding that there is no reason to use a whitelist in this situation.

Comment: There may be reasons to remove specific headers, but a whitelist really sounds like a silly idea. They are _response_ headers, there's nothing you can do to those to do anything to the actual response.

Comment: Thanks, that was my understanding too. I'll ask them to justify a whitelist and see what they say.

Comment: There are *very* specialized attacks that could be used in *some* circumstances such as [HTTP Smuggling](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Splitting/Smuggling_(OWASP-DV-016)) but I think your IT dept is either 1) overly paranoid or 2) overestimates the value of the data you have and sophistication of your attackers

Comment: I have the same problem at the moment and I fear I need to program like it's 1999 (the year of RFC 2616, HTTP 1.1). I can't control the firewalls installed in our customers networks. And they are less open to critique than our own admins.

Answer (score 2):

**Fingerprinting** could be the main reason to strip the response headers:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Fingerprint_Web_Server_%28OTG-INFO-002%29

It depends on the stack that you're running, and most of the time, the information included in the response headers is configurable in each server, but it requires tampering with each serving application individually (and there might be cases when the software is privative and doesn't offer the option to set the HTTP headers).

Let's go with an easy example:

*In our example datacenter, we're running a set of servers for different purposes, and we have configured them properly, so that they're returning no unnecessary metadata on the headers.*

*However, a new (imaginary) closed-source application for managing the print jobs is installed on one of the servers, and it offers a web interface that we want to use for whatever reason.
If this application returns an additional header such as (let's say) "x-printman-version" (and it might want to do that, to ensure compatibility with clients that use its API), it will be effectively exposing its version.*

And, if this print job manager has known vulnerabilities for certain versions, an attacker just has to query it to know whether this particular install is vulnerable.

This, that might not seem so important, **opens a window for automated/random attacks**, scanning ports of interests, and waiting for the right headers to appear ("fingerprints"), in order to launch an attack with certainty of success.

Therefore, stripping most (setting policies and rules for those that we want to keep) of the additional HTTP headers might sound sensible in an organisation.

With that being clear, **stripping the headers from outgoing connections responses is overkill**. It's true that they can constitute a vector, but since it's an outgoing connection, this means we "trust" the endpoint. There's no straightforward reason why an attacker with control over the trusted endpoint would use the metadata instead of the payload.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question about filtered response headers. Inbound.